# How does `az login` store credential information?

Tags: azure, credentials, azure-cli

I am wondering what happens when I am logging to azure using `az login` behind the scenes. I am still logged on for a long time, meaning that something is stored on the machine that allows access.

Would it be possible for an adversary who gains access to the harddrive to read that password/token in clear text to impersonate me?

P.S. I do not mean the credentials that are a part of the `az login` command itself, but data that is saved behind the scenes by the command.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Good question!

It doesn't store your login credentials but an authentication-refresh-token. The token can be changed by Microsoft or your tenant admin.

Refer:

> None of your login information is stored by Azure CLI. Instead, an
> authentication refresh token is generated by Azure and stored. As of
> August 2018 this token is revoked after 90 days of inactivity, but
> this value can be changed by Microsoft or your tenant administrator.
> Once the token is revoked you get a message from the CLI saying you
> need to login again.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli

The CLI stores the token and other details, like your profile, session details, etc. The details are stored in your Home folder.

> %HOMEPATH%  > .azure

navigate to `"%HOMEPATH%"` from run command (in Windows OS) and open ".Azure" folder. You will be able to find the files you're looking for.

[image]

---

(Update: Credit [IAmAliYousefi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2473837/iamaliyousefi))

If you use azure cli on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), the .azure directory won't be on your Linux WSL (i.e. ~/.azure), but it's on your Windows system. You can access it from your Linux WSL at /mnt/C/Users/YOUR_USERNAME/.azure/

---

You can consider cleaning it up the ".azure" folder when you're feeling "under-attack"

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So one of these files contains the refresh token, so anyone gaining access to that folder would be able to impersonate me for up to 90 days, right?

Comment: of course, it contains access-tokens in clear-text and anybody having access to it can impersonate you. So, the ".azure" folder or its contents shouldn't be shared in the public domain.

Comment: With the latest version of the az cli, the tokens are stored via DPAPI with the filename 'msal_token_cache.bin', you can decrypt it via UnProtectFile, I'm using Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal to let Msal handle the in-memory token caching... Having that said, any malware running under your account needs just one extra call to decode the token. And yes with the refresh token you can wreak havoc in your cloud.

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning that even if you use azure cli on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), the .azure directory won't be on your Linux WSL (i.e. ~/.azure), but it's on your Windows system. You can access it from your Linux WSL at ```/mnt/C/Users/YOUR_USERNAME/.azure/```

Comment: thanks @IAmAliYousefi - updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Also on Mac, looks like the corresponding token is stored here

```
~/.azure/msal_token_cache.json
```

I don't yet know how to do this on Azure, but in AWS land, the mechanism I used to mitigate an adversary abusing a secret they find in your home directory was to create a special user that has super specific/limited privileges/permissions , to help minimize your surface area.

I hope to one day learn how to do this in Azure too :)

Answer (score 0):

Good question!

You can encrypt your login data for security, following the steps on this site: https://www.sqlshack.com/different-ways-to-login-to-azure-automation-using-powershell/

Comment: I mean really not the credentials that we send in, but the credentials/token that is saved by the command itself. I have added it to the question to be more precise